# How to iterate through list of derived function objects and accessing derived objects member variables

Tags: c++, functor, derived-class

I have a function object definition:

```
struct BaseFunctor
{
    std::string desc = "Not this one!";
    virtual double operator()(double a, double (*func) (double)) = 0;
};
```

and a set of derived function object definitions:

```
struct DerivedFunctor1 : public BaseFunctor
{
    std::string desc = "Yes this!";
    virtual double operator()(double a, double (*func) (double))
    {
        return a * func(a);
    }
};

struct DerivedFunctor2 : public BaseFunctor
{
    std::string desc = "This is also correct!";
    virtual double operator()(double a, double (*func) (double))
    {
        return 5 * a * func(a);
    }
};
```

They are instantiated and used in the following way:

```
double f1(double x){
    return x*x+x;
}

template <typename T, typename F>
void do_something(T &func, F &derived)
{
    double a = 1.0;
    double res = derived(a, func);
    std::cout << derived.desc << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result is: " << res << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<BaseFunctor*> functors;
    DerivedFunctor1 *derived1 = new DerivedFunctor1;
    DerivedFunctor2 *derived2 = new DerivedFunctor2;
    functors.push_back(derived1);
    functors.push_back(derived2);

    for (auto &f : functors)
    {
        do_something(f1, *f);
    }
}
```

Now, the reason that the two function objects are derived from BaseFunctor was so I could collect them in a standard container and iterate through them. Are there other and more efficient ways to iterating through function objects?

Secondly, running the code outputs

```
Not this one!
Result is: 2
Not this one!
Result is: 10
```

When I try to access the member variable `desc`, I get the member variable of the parent class. I could write getters and get access to the member variables of the derived function objects in that way but that seems like a lot of work if there are many member variables to the function objects. Are there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: "seems like a lot of work" is a very good generic description of C++. Yes, you have to do a lot of work here, and this is not the only situation where a lot of work must be done in C++. The only way to access something in a derived class from a base class is by a virtual method call. The End.

Comment: What is `f1` in the `main` function?

Comment: In your specific case, when the list of functors is "known at compile time", a better way would be with a recursive template function. Something like `execute_all(derived1, derived2)`, I can explain how to implement it. If you want to maintain a dynamic list of callables, your way is the only way I know, although you should probably use `std::function` instead of creating classes.

Comment: @cigien, sorry forgot to add f1. I edited the question.

Comment: @NadavS if you could explain that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know which part of the answer to explain.

Comment: @NadavS the recursive template function

Comment: I put a code sample in an "answer" because it can't be pasted in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derived classes define another member named `desc` in addition to existing `BaseFunctor::desc`.

What you rather need is to initialize `BaseFunctor::desc` with the correct string. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct BaseFunctor {
    std::string const desc;
    virtual double operator()(double a, double (*func) (double)) = 0;
    virtual ~BaseFunctor() noexcept = default;
protected:
    BaseFunctor(std::string desc) noexcept
        : desc(move(desc))
    {}
};

struct DerivedFunctor1 : public BaseFunctor {
    DerivedFunctor1() : BaseFunctor("Yes this!") {}
    double operator()(double a, double (*func) (double)) override { return a * func(a); }
};

struct DerivedFunctor2 : public BaseFunctor {
    DerivedFunctor2() : BaseFunctor("This is also correct!") {}
    double operator()(double a, double (*func) (double)) override { return 5 * a * func(a); }
};

template <typename T>
void do_something(T &func, BaseFunctor &derived) {
    double a = 1.0;
    double res = derived(a, func);
    std::cout << derived.desc << '\n';
    std::cout << "Result is: " << res << '\n';
}

double f1(double a) noexcept { return a * a + a; }

int main() {
    using P = std::unique_ptr<BaseFunctor>;
    std::vector<P> functors;
    functors.push_back(P(new DerivedFunctor1));
    functors.push_back(P(new DerivedFunctor2));
    for (auto &f : functors)
        do_something(f1, *f);
}
```

A few other changes:

- `BaseFunctor` must have a `virtual` destructor if objects of derived classes get deleted through `BaseFunctor*`, and your code suggests that.
- Derived classes overridden functions should use `override` instead of `virtual` for the compiler to catch errors if you try to override a function that doesn't exists or have different parameters and/or return type. With `virtual` it introduces a new function overload with the same name, in this case.
- `std::unique_ptr` is used to avoid manual cleanup and leaking memory.
- `BaseFunctor::desc` made `const`, so that it must be initialized in the initializer list in `BaseFunctor`. That also makes `BaseFunctor` non-copyable and non-movable, which avoids accidental copy of derived class objects with slicing.

Answer (score 2):

Sample for calling a **constant number** of functions with the same parameters, as discussed in comments. See the (overloaded) function `call_all`:

```
#include <iostream>

void call_all() {
    // Does nothing, just stops the recursion.
}

template<typename Current, typename... Args>
void call_all(Current current_function, Args... args) {
    current_function();
    call_all(args...);
}

void func1() {
    std::cout << "func1" << std::endl;
}

void func2() {
    std::cout << "func2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Pass anything that implements operator() here.
    call_all(func1, func2);
}
```